# Pycharm 2.7: Internal HTTP server disabled

Tags: pycharm

I have installed pycharm 2.7 and each time I run it, the following message is shown on the left top corner in a red box:
Internal HTTP server disabled.
Cannot start internal HTTP server. Git integration, JavaScript debugger and LiveEdit may operate with errors. Please check your firewall settings and restart pycahrm.

And I checked firewall settings. I didn't see anything that might have caused this. What should I do?

Comment: What OS did you install it on?

Comment: The default port seems to be 63342, so check if you're running something else that might be using that port (use the netstat command if you're on Windows or Linux).

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and it worked:
Run command prompt as administrator - type `cmd` in the 'search programs and files' text box in the Windows Start menu; right-click and select 'Run as administrator'.

At the command prompt, type `netsh winsock reset`

Restart your PC

I got this from [Android studio "Cannot start internal HTTP server"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19889503/android-studio-cannot-start-internal-http-server)