# Android studio "Cannot start internal HTTP server"

Tags: android, android-studio

I'am trying to install Android studio, but bad luck..:-(.

- Windows 7
- Latest Andriod studio
- Latest Java
- Installed the latest Java and also added it to the system settings according to http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TTrUX1kUpDo
- Also downloaded Gradle and updated the system settings
- Stopped all firewall actions

So far so good, Android studio is also starting without any problems. But then I get two messages:

- Internal HTTP server disabled: Cannot start internal HTTP server. Git integration, JavaScript debugger and LiveEdit may operate with errors. Please check your firewall settings and restart Android Studio
- Gradle 'Nieuwproject' project refresh failed: Connection refused: connect

So after a few days of trying I was hoping that somebody could help me out..:-)

Comment: I described method to get it working here, on Stack: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33690567/2672951

Comment: I described method to get it working here, on Stack: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33690567/2672951

Comment: this works for me
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36738400/base-filtring-engine-service-issues-err-network-access-denied-and-can-not-start

Answer (score 13):

Here's what worked for me - I got the same error:

> Internal HTTP server disabled: Cannot start internal HTTP server. Git integration, JavaScript debugger and LiveEdit may operate with errors. Please check your firewall settings and restart Android Studio

Run command prompt as administrator - type `cmd` in the 'search programs and files' text box in the Windows Start menu; right-click and select 'Run as administrator'.

At the command prompt, type

```
netsh winsock reset
```

Restart your PC

This worked for me.

Just to mention: I also added Android Studio and Gradle folders to my virus protection exceptions in case it was being blocked, but that didn't resolve the problem;  the problem was only resolved once I followed the steps above.

Comment: >> command prompt, type: netsh winsock reset

I still can't solve that problem on my PC (Windows 7, x64, AS 2.3.3)
Nothing helps me. Approaches below do not work for me. I have no firewall (uninstalled) and Windows Firewall is turned OFF.
Also I tried to restart/turn off - 'Base Filtering Engine'. I do not have - 'Shell & ServicesEngine' at all.

Answer (score 2):

**Turn OFF firewall then turn ON again**.
Sometimes firewall blocks it automatically when you start your PC. It also blocks to internet browsing for other reason but restarting firewall may solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem after uninstalling Avast from my Computer,few days later i installed Avast again and the problem went away,Dont know what the connection is but thats what solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

if Shell&ServicesEngine is installed on your computer, uninstall it and restart the Android Studio.