# Couldn't connect to server (android studio 3.0.1) error

Tags: android-studio-3.0

I downloaded Android Studio 3.0.1 in my Windows 10 64bit and it shows this error.

> Error:Could not connect to server
>   [1a6902e5-d707-4db6-a658-c24ade784664 port:49832,
>   addresses:[/127.0.0.1]]. Tried addresses: [/127.0.0.1].
>
> Cannot start internal HTTP server. Git integration, JavaScript
>   debugger and LiveEdit may operate with errors. Please check your
>   firewall settings and restart Android Studio

I've tried

- closing the firewall,
- choose "no proxy form HTTP Proxy"

But none of these work!

How can I solve this?

Comment: Also - "Cannot start internal HTTP server".  "Please check your firewall settings". These are the first hints. Look for logs for the internal HTTP server. Also... maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19889503/812149) has some useful answers.

Comment: Ok, good work giving us more info! I've edited your question a bit further. Showing the message as a quote and making it more clear what you've tried. I'm giving you a vote to encourage you; **do** keep improving the question if you find more information! The more your readers know, the better your chance of getting a useful answer. Good luck!