# Gradle build error : Protocol Family Unavailable

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin

Hey guys i have been struggling to fix the problem on my Android Studio 3.0 because  every time i try to start a new projects its gives me this error while building it 
**Protocol Family Unavailable** and along with this error i also have this:

```
4:08 PM Cannot start internal HTTP server. Git integration, JavaScript debugger and LiveEdit may operate with errors. Please check your firewall settings and restart Android Studio
```

I already tried all the possible fixes given in this forum but none worked for me.

Comment: It's seems that your Android Studio cannot connect to internet. Are you under a corporate firewall? If yes, ask your admin to check why your Android Studio are not able to access internet. If not: are you on OSX or Windows? Do you use a VPN proxy?

Comment: I am running windows 10 64bit , Android studio was running perfectly in the ast few days ive made some changes in the firewall but i dont quite remmember. I tried disabling the anstivirus and windows firewall as well but nothing changed (and yes i have access to internet)

Comment: Have you tried to unistall and reinstall it? Are you able to try on a different PC?

Comment: I Re-installed it twice but still getting the error, I already have Android Studio installed on my main Desktop and Its running fine even offline.

Comment: Did you also try to start Window in safe mode and run AS? It really seems something that prevents AS to do something (seems starting an internal HTTP server). And try to think what's the difference between your main desktop and this PC in term of SW and Services installed.

Comment: You said you already tried also that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19889503/android-studio-cannot-start-internal-http-server, ain't it?

Comment: They are suggesting to disable the firewall but it is not the same case for me, also i tried running AS as Administrator but still, I ve restored the default settings for both the firewall and the the Network.